# Sending images over TCP from labVIEW to QT

Tags: c++, image, qt, tcp, labview

I am trying to capture images taken from a camera connected to a myRIO and send them over a TCP/IP connection from labVIEW to a QT GUI application.

My problem is that QT keeps throwing a heap pointer exception and crashing when I read the data.
Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

I believe this could be because the data being sent is over 35k bytes, so I tried to read the data in separate chunks, but alas am still getting the error.

Below is my function that gets called on readyRead() being emitted:

```
void TCPHandler::onRead() {


QByteArray byteArray;
QByteArray buffer;
QByteArray dataSize = mainSocket->read(5); //read the expected amount of bytes incoming (about 35000)
while (buffer.size() < dataSize.toInt()) {
    int bytesLeft = dataSize.toInt() - buffer.size();
    if (bytesLeft < 1024) {
        byteArray = mainSocket->read(bytesLeft);
    }
    else {
        byteArray = mainSocket->read(1024);
    }

    buffer.append(byteArray);
}
QBuffer imageBuffer(&buffer);
imageBuffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QImageReader reader(&imageBuffer, "JPEG");
QImage image;
if(reader.canRead())
    image = reader.read();
else {
    emit read("Cannot read image data");
}

if (!image.isNull())
{
    image.save("C:/temp");
}
else
{
    emit read(reader.errorString());
}}
```

In the LabVIEW code I send the size of the bytes being sent first, then the raw image data:

[image: LabVIEW code image]

EDIT: Connect for the slot. Also should have mentioned this is running in a separate thread to the Main GUI.

```
TCPHandler::TCPHandler(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent),
    bytesExpected(0)
{
    mainSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(mainSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onRead()));
    connect(mainSocket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &TCPHandler::displayError);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `connect` to this slot?

Comment: Are you sending the _expected amount of bytes incoming_ in every packet?

Comment: Edited to show the connect slot.
And yes I am sending the expected amount of bytes incoming in every packet. It depends on the length of the image data but its usually around 38000 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You assume that `onRead` is called with some particular number in bytes in question. All you are guaranteed is that there is at least one byte when `onRead` is entered. You perform no error checking. That's where your problems stem from, and it has nothing to do with sending "35kB at once": the wire protocol has to chunk it up to fit into MTUs anyway. Don't overthink it: TCP/IP data transmission pretty much works without any fuss with modern frameworks. If it doesn't work, it's due to bugs, not because you didn't perform some magic incantation.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your length  as a decimal string. Then followed by the string.
I would expect that the length would be binary value. So instead of an 'I32 to String' function use a [typecast](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/type_cast/) with a string as the type.